# I'm having trouble getting JavaScript variables passed to a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, phpmqtt

I'm trying to set up a webpage with Jquery that will receive button clicks from the user, pass those click values to a PHP script, that will then publish them to a MQTT broker. My connection to the broker seems to be working. I'm having problems passing variables from JavaScript to PHP. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button01").click(function(){$.post("post.php", {testvalue:test01});});
});
</script>
```

and here is my PHP:

```
<?php
require("../phpMQTT.php");

$testvalue = $_POST['testvalue'];

$mqtt = new phpMQTT("192.168.1.20", 8000, "client"); 

if ($mqtt->connect()) {
    $mqtt->publish("hello/world","$testvalue",0);
    $mqtt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Unless `test01` is a variable, it needs to be encapsulated in quotes...

Answer (score 1):

You pass invalid JSON object to `$.post()` method. It should be:

```
{testvalue:"test01"}
```

So your JavaScript code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button01").click(function(){$.post("post.php", {testvalue:"test01"});});
});
```

Or if `test01` is variable, it should be defined first.

Please, next time look at console in your browser and check if there is no errors and if the ajax call is sending correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  btw, the console wasn't giving me an error.